# Multi-digits bug code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very new to programming and decided to get into Python. Sorry in advance if this question is very simple. Experimenting with functions. Got this to run with no errors, but doesn't always work.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing the string replacement wrong? Any explanation or advice would be great.

Noticed it wasn't working when I was comparing a single digit number to a multi digit.

```
def bigger(a, b):
    if a > b:
        print ("%s is bigger" % a)
    elif a == b:
        print ("They are both equal!")
    else:
        print ("%s is bigger" % b)

a = input("Pick a number: ")
b = input("Pick another number: ")

bigger(a, b)
```

Comment: `input` returns a string.

Comment: Strings are compared using lexicographic sorting, like alphabetizing books.  So `"90"` is greater than `"100"` because `9` is greater than `1`.  Convert them to integers to order them like integers

Comment: So I have to specify that the input is an integer not a string? I guess I'll have to do some googling!

Comment: @Beckett change `a = input("Pick a number: ")` to `a = int(input("Pick a number: "))` and `b = input("Pick another number: ")` to `b = int(input("Pick another number: "))`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input("Pick a number: ")
b = input("Pick another number: ")
```

`input()` is always represented as a string and not an integer so in order to run comparisons like `if a > b` you must first convert it to an integer, like this:

```
a = int(input("Pick a number: "))
b = int(input("Pick another number: "))
```

The reason your program works is because Python is comparing the individual sizes of your strings.  So `"32"` starts with a 3 while `"122"` starts with a 1 so 32 is larger.

```
>>> '122'<'32'
True
>>> '44'>'1333333'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

input by default return String. You need to convert it to numbers. Change the int into float or double, if dealing with decimal numbers

```
def bigger(a, b):

    if int(a) > int(b):
        print ("%s is bigger" % a)
    elif a == b:
        print ("They are both equal!")
    else:
        print ("%s is bigger" % b)

a = input("Pick a number: ")
b = input("Pick another number: ")

bigger(a, b)
```